# How to send data and images with jquery in Model to Model.?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

i want to send price , name id and the first image from Model.Images to my cart controller but its not working i have 3 Images in my Model.Images tell me how to solve this problem.

**Summery Controller**

```cs
public IActionResult Summery(int id)
        {
            MobileModel m = new MobileHandler().GetMobile(id).ToModel();         
            return View(m);      
        }
```

**MobileModel class form where data is comming**

```cs
 public class MobileModel
    {
        public MobileModel()
        {
            Images = new List<string>();
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int Price  { get; set; }
        public List<string> Images { get; set; }
}
```

**Summery View**

```html
@{
@model MobileModel
}
<button type="submit" class="addcartbtn mt-5" data-pid="@Model.Id" data-pname="@Model.Name" data-pprice="@Model.Price" data-purl="@Model.Images[0]" data-pqty="1">
    <span class=" fa fa-shopping-cart"> Add To Cart</span>
</button>
```

**Jquery Code**

```
    $(".addcartbtn").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var obj = {
            "Id": $(this).data("pid"),
            "Name": $(this).data("pname"),
            "Price": $(this).data("pprice"),
            "Images": $(this).data("purl"),
            "Quantity": $(this).data("pqty")
        }
        $(this).parents("#proditem").fadeOut(300);
        $.ajax(
            {
                url: "/Cart/Add",
                type: "GET",
                data:  obj
            }
        ).done(function (itemscount) {
            $("#cartitems").text(itemscount);
    });
```

**CartModel Class**

```cs
public class ShoppingCartItem
{

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name  { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public string Images { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public int Amount { 
            get {
                return Quantity * Price;
                } 
        }
}
```

**Cart Controller where i want to send data**

```cs
 public class CartController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public int Add(ShoppingCartItem item)
        {
            ShoppingCart cart = HttpContext.Session.Get<ShoppingCart>(WebUtil.Cart);
            if (cart == null) cart = new ShoppingCart();
            cart.Add(item);
            HttpContext.Session.Set(WebUtil.Cart, cart);            
            return cart.NumberOfItems;
        }
```

Comment: Change your `type: "GET"` to `type: "POST"` in your `AJAX` call and change the `[HttpGet]` attribute to `[HttpPost]` on your `Controller` method.

Comment: @RahulSharma lol that's not an issue it's the basic of Programming.

Comment: You have mentioned that you want to SEND data which is `POST` to the server whereas `GET` is when you REQUEST data from the server. Maybe I have misunderstood your question. Please clarify what is your requirement.

Comment: @RahulSharma i am using get mathod bcz i am returning something from controller and with ajax it will still work with get mathod like this.. the problem is somthing is wrong with the Images its string in one class and List<string> in other that why its not working. i need solution for this code to work..

Comment: @AliRaza In fact, we cannot understand your problem. This code can successfully pass the ShoppingCartItem object to the Add method. What is your exact problem? Please describe clearly.

Comment: @YongqingYu the problem is somewhere in Images
1. List<string> to string for images jquery code not working.
2. List<string> to List<string> its working but i don't want that.
3. i tried to use byte[] then its send null in images.. 
i need List<string> to string and this code to run fine that the problem i dont know how to explain better then this.

Comment: @AliRaza, so is this code currently feasible?  data-purl="@Model.Images[0]"  has changed List<string> into a string type.

Comment: @YongqingYu i thought it should worked like that but its not working llike this.

Comment: @YongqingYu no its not changing it ..jquery code is not working with List<string> to string. need some other solution...thats why i am asking.